# Getting "Uncaught Action failed" with "not defined" error in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

Here is the error

> Uncaught Action failed: c:BusinessEventEdit2$controller$showAlloc
>   [tlist is not defined]

**Lightning Component**

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-more slds-m-left--x-small iconsize" aria-haspopup="true" onclick="{!c.showAlloc}">
                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:table"  size="x-small" variant="bare" class="slds-button__icon"/>
                    <!--
                    <c:svg ariaHidden="true" class="slds-button__icon"
                           xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS201/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#table">
                    </c:svg>-->
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Table</span>                    
                </button>
```

**Client side controller**

```
showAlloc: function(component, event, helper){
    debugger;
    helper.processEvent(component);               
}
```

**Helper**

```
processEvent: function(cmp){
        debugger;
        var bizev = cmp.get("v.bizev");
        var trans = cmp.get("v.trans");
        var allocs = cmp.get("v.alloc");                
        //bizev.Transactions__r = trans;
        var action = cmp.get("c.ProcessEvent");

        var transList = [];

        if(allocs){
            var i = 0, p = 0;                                        
            for(i = 0; i < trans.length; i++){  
                var isAuto = false;
                for(p=0;p < allocs.Allocs.length; p++){
                    if(trans[i].Sequence__c == allocs.Allocs[p].Trans.Sequence__c){
                        debugger;  
                        isAuto = allocs.Allocs[p].AutoCreated;
                        break;  
                    }
                }
                if(!isAuto){
                    transList.push(trans[i]);
                }                
            }
        }
        else //Never processed before
        {
           transList = trans; 
        }

        action.setParams({  ev: bizev,
                          tlist: transList}); 
        console.log("current text: " + tlist);
        console.log("current text: " + ev);
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            debugger;            
            var data = response.getReturnValue();
            debugger;
            if(data){
                if(data.Status){  
                    cmp.set("v.alloc", data);  

                    var translist = cmp.get("v.trans");
                    translist.splice(0, translist.length);

                    data.Allocs.forEach(function(element) {
                        translist.push(element.Trans);
                    }, this);

                    cmp.set("v.trans", translist);

                    this.showAllocWindow(cmp);
                }
                else{
                    throw new Error(data.Message);
                }                    
            }else{
                throw new Error("Error during allocation!");            
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Hi Vikas, can you explain what you don't understand? what part of your code doesnt seem to be working? the error is pretty straightforward -> [tlist is not defined] .

Comment: Just replace this line: `action.setParams({  ev: bizev, tlist: transList});`  by :`action.setParams({  "ev": bizev, "tlist": transList});`. The `setParams` expects a map with properties declared as string.

Comment: @MartinLezer JavaScript objects don't require the quotes (though JSON does).

Comment: @MartinLeze I use the same as you mention but error is same, I am new in lightning so that I can't be understands where is problem

Comment: @vikasrathi Please post your Apex controller code.

Comment: @MartinLeze Thanks for your valuable time. Now I am resolve that problem Its a simple Javascript Error.I am find that through Debug. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In this code you have made `tlist` a property of an object that you don't hold a reference to so can't access that property value:

```
    action.setParams({ev: bizev, tlist: transList});
```

You could instead look at the values you assigned for debugging purposes like this:

```
    console.log("bizev: " + bizev);
    console.log("transList: " + transList);
```

or better probably to do this:

```
     console.log("params: " + JSON.stringify(action.getParams()));
```